# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net, postgresql-9.1

I Create Project VB.NET Export data to Excels. But error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I Connect Database Postgresql Use PostgreSQL ODBC Driver (psqlODBC).

MainForm.vb

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc


Public Class MainForm
Private Function getDemoDataSet() As DataSet

    Dim MyCon As New Odbc.OdbcConnection
    MyCon.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};database=tscon;server=192.168.3.60;port=5432;uid=postgres;sslmode=disable;readonly=0;protocol=7.4;User ID=postgres;password=1234;"
    Dim da As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim str2 As String
    MyCon.Open()
    str2 = "select * from entity_tbl"
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(str2, MyCon)
    da.Fill(ds)
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Customer0"
    MyCon.Close()



    Return ds
End Function

Private Sub startDemoButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles startDemoButton.Click
    ' Prepare the output filenames
    Dim timeMark As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HHmmss")
    ''Dim cellByCellFilePath As String = "C:\ExcelExportCellByCell_" + timeMark + ".xls"
    Dim fastExportFilePath As String = "D:\" + timeMark + ".xls"

    Me.demoResultListBox.Items.Clear()

    ' Object to mark the times for each process
    Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch()
    Me.UseWaitCursor = True

    Try
        ' Get the demo DataSet
        stopwatch.Start()
        Dim demoDataSet As DataSet = Me.getDemoDataSet()
        stopwatch.Stop()

        Me.demoResultListBox.Items.Add("* Generate DEMO DataSet: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString())
        stopwatch.Reset()

        ' '' Use the "Copy-cell-by-cell" method
        ''stopwatch.Start()
        ''ExportingCellByCellMethod.ExportToExcel(demoDataSet, cellByCellFilePath)
        ''stopwatch.Stop()

        ''Me.demoResultListBox.Items.Add("* COPY CELL-BY-CELL method: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString())
        ''stopwatch.Reset()

        ' Use the "fast export" method
        stopwatch.Start()
        FastExportingMethod.ExportToExcel(demoDataSet, fastExportFilePath)
        stopwatch.Stop()

        Me.demoResultListBox.Items.Add("* FAST EXPORT method: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString())
        stopwatch.Reset()

    Finally
        Me.UseWaitCursor = False
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Module FastExportingMethod.vb

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module FastExportingMethod

Public Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal outputPath As String)
    ' Create the Excel Application object
    'Dim excelApp As New ApplicationClass()
    Dim excelApp As New Excel.Application()

    ' Create a new Excel Workbook
    Dim excelWorkbook As Workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)


    Dim sheetIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim col, row As Integer
    Dim excelSheet As Worksheet



    ' Copy each DataTable as a new Sheet
    For Each dt As System.Data.DataTable In dataSet.Tables

        sheetIndex += 1

        ' Copy the DataTable to an object array
        Dim rawData(dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count - 1) As Object

        ' Copy the column names to the first row of the object array
        For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            rawData(0, col) = dt.Columns(col).ColumnName
        Next

        ' Copy the values to the object array
        For col = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            For row = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                rawData(row + 1, col) = dt.Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
            Next
        Next

        ' Calculate the final column letter
        Dim finalColLetter As String = String.Empty
        Dim colCharset As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        Dim colCharsetLen As Integer = colCharset.Length

        If dt.Columns.Count > colCharsetLen Then
            finalColLetter = colCharset.Substring( _
             (dt.Columns.Count - 1) \ colCharsetLen - 1, 1)
        End If

        finalColLetter += colCharset.Substring( _
          (dt.Columns.Count - 1) Mod colCharsetLen, 1)

        ' Create a new Sheet
        excelSheet = CType( _
            excelWorkbook.Sheets.Add(excelWorkbook.Sheets(sheetIndex), _
            Type.Missing, 1, XlSheetType.xlWorksheet), Worksheet)

        excelSheet.Name = dt.TableName

        ' Fast data export to Excel
        Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1)
        excelSheet.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData

        ' Mark the first row as BOLD
        CType(excelSheet.Rows(1, Type.Missing), Range).Font.Bold = True

        excelSheet = Nothing
    Next

    ' Save and Close the Workbook
    excelWorkbook.SaveAs(outputPath, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, _
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, _
     Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

    excelWorkbook.Close(True, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)

    excelWorkbook = Nothing

    ' Release the Application object
    excelApp.Quit()
    excelApp = Nothing

    ' Collect the unreferenced objects
    GC.Collect()
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Put a Try Catch, and show us more info of that exception

Comment: error : da.Fill(ds)   > An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: First of all, did you installed the ODBC drivers?

Comment: i installed the ODBC drivers pgsqlodbc .